# Did I get hit by the recent Java exploit?

Tags: exploit, java, macos

Looks like the website [iphonedevsdk was responsible](http://allthingsd.com/20130219/this-is-the-site-likely-responsible-for-the-recent-major-tech-company-hacks) for serving up the malware that's been causing some of the recent security exploits. According to my browser history, I visited that site back in December. I've had Java turned off in my browsers since forever, but I do have it installed in the OS (OS X 10.8). I did install the security update from Apple yesterday (2/19).

Comment: No, but the ad banners on that porn site exploited your browser ages ago.

Comment: Very localized question, and ill suited to the site.  Can you rephrase the question so that the answer has value to the rest of the universe?

Comment: According to this article http://www.informationweek.com/security/attacks/apple-facebook-twitter-attacks-6-key-fac/240148906?cid=RSSfeed_IWK_ALL the attack was in several stages with JavaScript not Java method of hitting the site visitors so disabled Java would not be a protection.

Answer (score 3):

If Java is turned off, it is unlikely that a Java exploit could have hit you as it would have first had to exploit the browser in to executing Java despite being off.  It is worth clarifying that Java and JavaScript are not at all related though and verify that it is in fact Java that you have disabled.